# Alternative to Apache libraries for an FTP client and server?

Tags: java, ftp

I am having fun (sort of) developing a Java 7 [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) implementation for use with FTP servers; for this I need an FTP client library (for the runtime aspect) and an FTP server library (for tests).

So, let us start with...

### The `FileSystem` API

A `FileSystem` is an abstraction, introduced in Java 7, allowing to accessing a tree of [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)s. Think directories and files and you won't be far from reality (note that symbolic link support is also there but we will get it out of the picture for now).

A `FileSystem` is a collection of [`FileStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html)s; a `FileSystem` can potentially have more than one `FileStore` but this is FTP; only one `FileStore` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getFileStores%28%29)). One important aspect of a `FileStore` is that it describes what "attributes" are available (see [`AttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AttributeView.html)).

Once you have implemented `FileStore`, `FileSystem` and `Path`, you can then do such niceties as, for instance, copy a remote file to a local file using `Files.copy()`:

```
final Path ftpsrc = ftpfs.getPath(somePathHere);
// Paths.get() gets a path from the default JRE filesystem
final Path localdst = Paths.get(somePathHere);
Files.copy(ftpsrc, localdst);
```

### The client side

What I need on the client side is a minimal library to implement FTP with at least basic authentication support, passive/active mode, binary transfer mode, SSL/TLS support. Download resume is not required.

Right now, my choice is:

commons-net:commons-net:3.3

It has good reputation, its license matches my needs (I will eventually publish the project using dual LGPLv3/ASL 2.0 licensing) and implements all I want.

But it implements much more than FTP proper. While it does the job, it looks like a 2 squared-mile brick to squash a mouse. Is there an alternative library with as friendly a license as this one but doesn't try and implement anything beyond FTP?

### The server side

What is needed here is a pure Java implementation; I need to be able to instantiate an FTP serve so that I can test my implementation against it. Right now, I have elected this one:

org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-code:1.0.6 (server).

The reasons I have chosen it are pretty much the same as for commons-net. But maybe there is a better one?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! If you are looking for an alternative to something, please do point out what of the current solution is lacking. WHY do you look for a different solution? Also your question needs far more details on what you do, in what environment you use it and what you want to optimize against. Currently every and any FTP Library in Java would match which is too broad for this site.

Comment: Also, why do you need a server to test something? Why not mock it for the automation? Or is that something that you would consider "an alternative"?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer simple enough; I want to test that my `FileSystem` implementation works without requiring that an FTP server be installed on the system.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer edited the post to answer your first requirement; on the client side I am looking for a potentially more lightweight solution

Comment: Your basic FTP Client methods can be mocked to call an internal method. Thus no server is necessary. All your richer methods would then call the mocked methods. To show that you need a server you have to give more detail (which you should do anyway)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I fail to see what further details you are looking for; the only details I can provide further than that is add a link to Java 7's javadoc of `FileSystem`...

Comment: Your edit: Better, but "lightweight" is in itself kinda vague. What functions of FTP are you calling? Do you want a "pure FTP" library that does not implement all the other protocols that commons-net does implement? If so: Why?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer because I am implementing a `FileSystem` for FTP, and FTP only

Comment: The RFC for FTP lists LOTS of commands that can be issued over FTP. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html Which of them do you use? Not every library supports all of them (which is a major distinction). What real server will be the end point for your library (or just "any")?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer only the minimal command set necessary to obey the `FileSystem` interface; may evolve when I advance in this project... For instance, I will only start with the strict minimum `FileAttributeView`s; but this will evolve with time, of course

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13631/discussion-between-angelo-neuschitzer-and-fge)

Comment: For the client lib, this seems to be answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295178/what-java-ftp-client-library-should-i-use